# Android studio button bug not responding to clicks

Tags: java, android, xml

Creating a soundboard on android studio and there is this annoying bug which makes that sometimes the buttons don't respond to the clicks. Then I restart the app and the buttons work, however other buttons stop working.. its really weird.

Comment: share your code plz so that we can help

Comment: a man needs some code

Comment: Test other Android OS Versions, Update Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related the current version of JDK android studio is using and especially if you drag and drop a file inside android studio try to update you JDK